# jquery addClass and removeClass on Click

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have something like this. 
Why doesn't this work? 
I just want the rows with .inactive class to be clickable. And when a row is clicked it should get the .active class.

Sorry for bad coding, jQuery beginner.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#shipping_table tr.inactive').on("click",function(){
    $('#shipping_table tr').removeClass("active");
    $('#shipping_table tr').addClass("inactive");

    $(this).removeClass("inactive");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    //Some more stuff

});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="shipping_table">
   <tr class="active">
      <td>Row 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="inactive">
      <td>Row 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="inactive">
      <td>Row 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're not closing the `<td>`

Comment: See [Demostration](http://jsfiddle.net/z7HUv/)

Comment: I updated the post with correct closing </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#shipping_table').on('click', 'tr.inactive', function(){ });
```

It will dynamically bind event to all `tr.inactive` elements if they occurs during the runtime.

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7HUv/)

Comment: Why would some one down-vote answer? Even weird without leaving a comment. I have added demo in your answer

Comment: Yours is first correct answer. I have nullified downvote

Answer (score 0):

you are executing this function only when an onclick occurs on a tr with class .inactive. os if you change the selector it should work.

```
$('#shipping_table tr').on("click",function(){
   $('#shipping_table tr').removeClass("active");
   $('#shipping_table tr').addClass("inactive");
   $(this).removeClass("inactive");
   $(this).addClass("active");

  //Some more stuff

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try without class `.inactive` in the selector, 
because every `tr` should be clickable, not only with (initial)class `.inactive`

```
$('#shipping_table tr').on("click",function(){
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2FrtM/6/)**